# In Javascript, How do I Get the key given an object as value?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let, an array with named keys and object values as follows:

```
var a={};
a["1a"] = {prop1:"1",prop2:"qwe1"};
a["2a"] = {prop1:"2",prop2:"qwe2"};
a["3a"] = {prop1:"3",prop2:"qwe3"};
```

How do I find the key "2a" when the value `{prop1:"2",prop2:"qwe2"}` is given. Thank you in advance. Sorry if the question was repeated.

Comment: What have you done so far? :)

Comment: is the given object the same with same object reference or is it another objetc with same key/value pairs? ahve you looked into your last closed duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663970/index-of-object-in-node-js)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to get an array of the keys and values, loop through them, and find the ones that match your criteria. You can use `Object.entries(a)` to get key value pairs. Next you can use `Array.find` to look for the matching one. For example:

```
const [k, v] = Object.entries(a).find(([k, v]) => {
    return v.prop1 === '2' && v.prop2 === 'qwe2';
});
```